# Is Python 3.5 supported and working with Postgresql?

Tags: python, django, postgresql

I've searched all over Google trying to find out if I can use a Django 1.9 stack with Python 3.5 and using Postgresql.  I wanted to verify this beforehand since I have already tried to go down that road with MySQL, but unfortunately that is yet to be supported, at least with a Windows development environment.

Can anybody confirm they have gotten this setup working?

Comment: if psychopg works I would expect the rest to also

Comment: @JoranBeasley psycopg2. No h. Your biggest roadblock will probably be Django not psycopg2, but the documentation for Django says that 1.9 supports Python 3.5 so it should be OK.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Django officially mentions it's compatible with Python 3.5 and has been since version 1.8 ([see release notes here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/releases/1.9/#python-compatibility)).

Pyscopg2 is required to get Python/Django to work with PostgreSQL. Although their website says they only support up to Python 3.4, there's nothing stopping you from using Python 3.5. Since you mentioned you're working in Windows, you can find the latest version of pyscopg2 compiled and ready to use with Python 3.5 [here](http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/).

Anecdotally, I currently have a project running Django 1.9 in a Python 3.5 environment with PostgreSQL and it works fine, I'm on OS X.

Comment: awesome, thank you for the information and the link!